# Google Chrome Extension and document.getElementbyId().click()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Long time reader, first time question asker. I have seen a lot of similar questions as I try to figure this out but for the life of me I just can't get this up and running. I haven't done much Javascript so while I've been reading a lot of links to documentation, I can't always wrap my head around it.

One of my company's vendors has a ["Sign in with Google"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) button on my company's custom domain. We use Google Identities, so we always have an active Google session, but the vendor says the button has to be clicked. I figured it would be easy to create a Chrome Extension that will click the button as soon as we land on the vendor's page.

From the console in dev tools I can run the following line which will activate the button and start the authentication flow, so this part works manually:

```
document.getElementById('googleSignInButton').click();
```

I've tried a few different solutions so my 'manifest.json', 'background.js', and 'ClickButton.js' are a little helter skelter, apologies.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "ClickButton",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Clicks Sign in with Google Button",
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
   },
  "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "webNavigation", "tabs", "https://www.vendor.com/"],
  "browser_action":{
    "default_title": "Title"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://www.vendor.com/*"],
     "all_frames": true,
     "run_at": "document_end",
     "js": ["ClickButton.js"]
   }
 ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
//When I run this code in background.js it works as it requires me to click the plugin button
//Clicking the plugin button will run ClickButton.js and it will activate the "googleSignInButton"
/*
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'ClickButton.js'
    });
});
*/

//This is the chunk of code pulled from Google's Getting Started Tutorial https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted
//This will load ClickButton.js when I am just running alert. It also loads the ClickButton.js when I am actually trying to click the "googleSignInButton"

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.vendor.com'},
        })
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.RequestContentScript({js: ["ClickButton.js"]})]
      }]);
});
```

ClickButton.js

```
document.getElementById('googleSignInButton').click();

//When I am just running an alert, this pops up when I navigate to my vendor's page, so JS should be getting injected
/*alert ("Test");*/
```

I've tried a bunch of different types of troubleshooting. As you can see from background.js and ClickButton.js, I have commented out some of my tests. When I use chrome.browserAction.onClicked I can manually initiate the javascript to click the button, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

The error that I get in my Extensions when using chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher (i.e. not manually clicking the extension) is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

Which from what I can gather means that the DOM maybe isn't loaded when the Extension tries to run. This is why I have tried both document_idle (per the  [Content Scripts documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)) as well as document_end, thinking maybe the DOM isn't ready yet. I have also tried setTimeout just to wait it out but it still won't run without the above error.

I have also referenced Dan Harper's [bare minimum Chrome extension.](https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399) I can get his Javascript to run when I click a button:

```
(function() {

    // just place a div at top right
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.textContent = 'Injected!';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    alert('inserted self... giggity');

})();
```

but when I try to have it run as soon as I hit the page, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

Which makes me think that in this case there is an issue with document.body.appendChild(div), and maybe the extension trying to run before everything is loaded.

It may also be a permission issue where the script is not able to access the 'googleSignInButton' that is on the page. I tried to set the permissions to the vendor's website in the manifest.json as best as I could understand.

I apologize for the length of my question! But I've really been trying a lot of different ways to get this working and I've done a lot of Google searching. I just can't figure out. Hopefully someone can assist.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually it means the element is added by the page script after the initial load event (here your content script runs) so you can simply wait using setTimeout for like 100ms then retry and repeat or MutationObserver (all inside your content script.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for getting back to me! I'm sorry for the delay, work projects have been busy.

I have actually tried a setTimout on my content script (ClickButton.js)

`setTimeout(5000);`


`document.getElementById('googleSignInButton').click();`


I know it's a long timeout but I just wanted to be sure everything was loaded. Still getting the same behavior as before.

Comment: This is not how setTimeout is used though... setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById('googleSignInButton').click(); }, 5000);

Comment: Haha well that would explain a lot!

I made that change to correctly use it and now it works, thank you very much!

I did notice that the popup was initially blocked by my browser. I went back to try some of my other code but did not notice any popups being made. Since this is kind of a workaround, I will stick to the setTimeout workaround.

Thank you again for your help!